# If mobile disable certain scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able disable certain scripts that are in the head section of my page when a mobile device is detected.

At the minute I have this:

```
$(function(){
    var mobile;
    if (window.width <= 479) {
        //don't load these scripts 
    }
    else {
        //load all scripts
    }
});
```

I'm struggling to find the code to disable the scripts from running when mobile width is detected. Any help or other ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: use if (window.width > 479) { //Now only include script}

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That's a much better idea. I'm struggling to find the code to load the scripts though, do you have any ideas?

Comment: `window.screen.width` will give you the device width which might be better for mobiles. I'd also check out [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and it's script loader [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use following

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}else
{
//Now include js files
}
```

for your second Question

use

```
if (window.width > 479) {
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

here you can include  css or js file.

Comment: This answer is from 2014, is this still the best way to do this? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // what you want to run in mobile
}
```

you can do something like this to test if it is a mobile.

if you are only concerned with the width :

```
if ($(window).width() <= 479) {
     do stuff
}
```

or you can use this [package](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/).