# How to block PCs from being able to access a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code blocking phones:

```
if {
    /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i
    .test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location = "www.zentriamc.com/teachers/error.html"
}
```

How would I use this code (or different code) on another webpage, to block computers (not strictly PCs. Just every device NOT listed above)?

Comment: What exactly does not works in your code?

Comment: Can you just 'not' the whole list if that list is definitely all you want?

Comment: +Ludovic The code is fine. The code blocks phones. What I'm asking is how I would use like an else statement to block computers. I tried simply using an else statement but it didn't work.

Comment: +BSMP I have tried adding "not" after "if". But it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If mobile disable certain scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680448/if-mobile-disable-certain-scripts)

Comment: It might have been a problem with the parenthesis, `if (!([blah])) {...}`, but the if/else in the dupe should work.

Comment: It is important to note that _this will not block_ a device from accessing the webpage. Instead, the correct analogy would be that the webpage is sent to the client regardless, and then it is up to the client to decide whether it wants to block it for itself or not. This is fine for presentation purposes (for example, when a page is accidentally viewed by a device it was not meant for), but not for any kind of security, as the client _will_ receive the page contents every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else should work just fine...

```
if {
        /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i
        .test(navigator.userAgent)) {
} else {
        window.location = "somepage.html"
}
```